# Rails use `where` with multi-level association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have 3 models liks this:

```
Institution
  has_many :users

User
  belongs_to :insitution
  has_many :incomes

Income
  belongs_to :user
```

How I can find Incomes with

`user.institution.sub=false`

Something like this:

```
Income.joins(:user).where('user.institution.sub = ?', false)
```

Help please, I seeking for solutions about 2 hours and nothing suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Income.joins(user: :institution).where(institutions: {sub: false})
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I already tried this and get this error

Association named 'instituion' was not found on User; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: @ssbb no, it's probably you who misspelled it. :)

Comment: I guess you really mispelled it, according to your code you used `belongs_to :insittution`